# Calculate string difference between consecutive and categorized rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Unfortunately, I accidentally inserted all my comments concatenated every time in my table. I would like to fix this in my database like in the example:

My table is:

| ID | Category_ID | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abcd |
| 2 | 1 | abcd efg |
| 3 | 1 | abcd efg hij |
| 4 | 2 | onetwo |
| 5 | 2 | onetwo three |
| 6 | 3 | some |
| 7 | 3 | some |

It should be as follows:

| ID | Category_ID | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abcd |
| 2 | 1 | efg |
| 3 | 1 | hij |
| 4 | 2 | onetwo |
| 5 | 2 | three |
| 6 | 3 | some |
| 7 | 3 |  |

I appreciate your help

Comment: Which command are you using actually ? Can you add what you tried in your post ?

Answer (score 2):

You can utlise `lag` here:

```
select *, 
  trim(Replace(comment, Lag(comment,1,'') 
    over(partition by category_id order by id), '')) Corrected
from t;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=397c8d59deac12a6665fa296cabcf17b)

After checking the results are as expected you can then use an updatable CTE to correct the data:

```
with fixy as (
  select *, 
    trim(Replace(comment, Lag(comment,1,'') 
     over(partition by category_id order by id), '')) Corrected
  from t
)
update fixy set comment = corrected;
```

Comment: Very good. I was about to do something involving a rCTE but this is much better